# Matrix inequalities in series form

Tags: matrix-theory, power-series

While studying the positivity of mechanical systems, we land on the following conjecture but don't know how to prove this.

If a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ satisfies both the two following inequalities:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A^n \dfrac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!} \geq 0 \ \mbox{ for all } \ t\geq 0;  \label{1} \\
& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A^n \dfrac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \geq 0 \mbox{ for all } t\geq 0,
\end{align}
then $A \geq 0$.
**Here $\geq 0$ means that all the elements of a matrix are non-negative, but not in the sense of positive definiteness.**

It is quite clear, that by letting $t$ sufficiently small, from the 1st inequality, we see that matrix A is Metzler, i.e., $a_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i \not= j$. However, I don't know how to handle diagonal elements $a_{ii}$.

Any suggestions or comments are very welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please double-check your indices; I imagine that the sum is not over $i$, and that $n$ inside the sum is not the dimension of $A$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : I have taken the liberty to edit the post in accordance with your comment.

Comment: Thank you @Iosif Pinelis. I tried MATLAB and it shows exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample is given by
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & a \\
 a & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
with (say) $a=2$.

Indeed, then the sum of your first series is
$$c(t):=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}
 c_+(t) & c_-t) \\
 c_-(t) & c_+(t) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
with
$$c_\pm(t):=\cosh t\pm\cos \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)\ge1-1=0$$
for real $t$, and the sum of your second series is
$$s(t):=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}
 s_+(t) & s_-t) \\
 s_-(t) & s_+(t) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
with
$$s_\pm(t):=\sinh t\pm\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\ge0$$
for real $t\ge0$, because $s_\pm(0)=0$ and $s'_\pm=c_\pm\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you @Iosif Pinelis. I tried MATLAB and it shows exactly the same.

Comment: So, are you satisfied with this answer?

Comment: Definitely. Thanks again @Iosif Pinelis.

Comment: @IscoBerlin : Great. Just in case, if you are not yet familiar with [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) ...